# Alternative for full outer join in indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to display records from two tables.

It should return all the matching records from both the tables.

If a record is present in first table and not present in second table it should return null from the Second table and records from the first table.
If a record is present in second table and not present in first table it should return null from the first table and records from the second table

I don't want to use a `full outer join`, because I want to create an indexed view and outer(Left, Right, Full) joins are not allowed in Indexed View.

Is there any better solution for this scenario.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `full join`? It is meant for situations like this

Comment: The alternative is a union over two left joins. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes, but I didn't realise you wrote it until now, whoops, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [workaround](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/indexedviewswithouterjoins/1884/) for indexed views with 'emulated outer joins'. However, it's hideous and I wouldn't advocate it.

A better solution would be to index the underlying tables and skip the whole view. Or create two indexed views and do the `outer join` in the query calling the views.

Yet another solution is to not create an indexed view, but an actual table (which you can keep up-to-date with triggers) and put indexes on that. Since you're materializing the view anyway, this might be the best solution.

In all likelihood, an indexed view (whichever method you choose) won't give you the (performance) result you are looking for (though the last method where you create an actual table might). Can you explain why you feel you need an indexed view in this particular case?

By the way, [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/29/sql-server-outer-join-not-allowed-in-indexed-views/) is a (short) explanation **why** indexed views don't allow `outer joins`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. For future questions you might like to explain your requirements a bit more. You got downvoted a lot because people didn't know why you couldn't use outer joins.

Comment: _"By the way, here is a (short) explanation why indexed views don't allow outer joins."_ - Pinal's explanation is that `x OUTER JOIN y` can be used with `WHERE y IS NULL` to create an anti-join, which reduces rows, which is incompatible with how indexed-views work, but that doesn't explain why a query using `OUTER JOIN` _without_ being an anti-join shouldn't work.

Comment: @Dai "[it is] relatively complex to implement", is the short answer here. Detecting an `OUTER JOIN` is simple, qualifying the join in this way is much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

given your requirement you should use full outer join. In case you want an alternative.. u can use the approach below.

```
sel cola,colb,colc... from table a where colmnlist not in (select columnlist     from  table b )
union all
sel cola,colb,colc from table b where colmnlist not in (select columnlist     from  table a )
```

But any specific reason as to why you want to avoid full outer join in this case.

Comment: Note that UNION removes duplicates, FULL OUTER JOIN doesn't.

Comment: right right.. i just wanted to give a rough draft of the logic.. ideally it should be union all in this case @jarlh

Comment: I want to create Indexed View and Outer Join Not Allowed in Indexed Views.

Comment: in that case you can use the solution I provided above. let me know if its working @Prince

Comment: No Outer(Left, Right, Full) join allowed in Indexed View. @ Aritra

Comment: ok.. let me modify the logic.. i will post the draft, you can put in the required columns and tablenames. @Prince

Comment: `UNION` is also not supported in an indexed view